# I can't connect to db or pull data

Tags: php, mysql

I am using this same code `

```
php $postId = 41;

<!-- hidden items and variables. Elements that will not be revealed !--> 

<span  id="gameLength"><?php 

// MySQL connect configuration

$dbname="my_db";

$host="localhost";

$user="guessthe";

$dbh=mysql_connect ($host,$user,"correctPassword?") or die ('I cannot connect to the database because: ' . mysql_error(). '');

mysql_select_db ("$dbname") or die('I cannot select the database because: ' . mysql_error());

$sql="SELECT * FROM games WHERE postId = $postId";

$result=mysql_query($sql);

$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);

$gameId = $rows['id']; 

$game100s = $rows['game100s']; 

$gamesPlayedAllTime = $rows['gamesPlayed']; 

$gamesPointsAllTime = $rows['gameScore']; 

$gameLength = $rows['gameLength']; // get number of questions

$gameScore = $rows['gameScore'];

$gameType = $rows['gameType'];

$gametitle = $rows['gameSubTitle'];

echo $gameLength;
```

There is a value in the gameLength row! I can't get this code to pull any of the rows! Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: run the sql in any mysql client such as phpMyAdmin and see if it works, and I wonder why $postID is specified outside the php tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using MySQL, which is depcirated - and will be phased out. You should use MySQLi or PDO instead. Also, your `$postId` is defined outside a PHP-tag? Might just be a copy/paste mistake? Anyway, you can try the code below, which is in MySQLi:

```
<?php 
    $postId = 41; 
?>

<!-- hidden items and variables. Elements that will not be revealed !--> 

<span  id="gameLength"><?php 

// MySQL connect configuration
$dbname = "my_db";
$host   = "localhost";
$user   = "guessthe";

// Connecting to the database
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, "correctPassword?", $dbname);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    // If we are here, the connection failed
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (".$mysqli->connect_errno.") ".$mysqli->connect_error;
}

$sql ="SELECT * FROM games WHERE postId = $postId";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
    // If the query was sucsessfull, we can get the rows
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $gameId             = $row['id']; 
        $game100s           = $row['game100s']; 
        $gamesPlayedAllTime = $row['gamesPlayed']; 
        $gamesPointsAllTime = $row['gameScore']; 
        $gameLength         = $row['gameLength']; // get number of questions
        $gameScore          = $row['gameScore'];
        $gameType           = $row['gameType'];
        $gametitle          = $row['gameSubTitle'];
    }
} else {
    // If the query failed, do something here
}

echo $gameLength;
?>
```

I see some people commenting that you need to put the `$postId` variable inside quotes in the query, but when using double-quotes (") variables will be posted, so it's not really needed. Also note that things are case-sensitive, so if your results doesn't show, check for spelling-mistakes.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. When I plugged your code in it works. I will be sure to take note. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

There are many errors in your code

Try this...

```
<?php

$postId = 41;

?>
<!-- hidden items and variables. Elements that will not be revealed !--> 

<span  id="gameLength">
<?php 

// MySQL connect configuration

$host = "localhost";
$dbname = "my_db";
$user = "username";
$password = "password";

$dbh = mysql_connect ($host,$user,$password) or die ('I cannot connect to the database because: ' . mysql_error() . '');

mysql_select_db($dbname, $dbh) or die('I cannot select the database because: ' . mysql_error());

$sql = "SELECT * FROM games WHERE postId='$postId'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   $gameId = $rows['id']; 
   $game100s = $rows['game100s']; 
   $gamesPlayedAllTime = $rows['gamesPlayed']; 
   $gamesPointsAllTime = $rows['gameScore']; 
   $gameLength = $rows['gameLength']; // get number of questions
   $gameScore = $rows['gameScore'];
   $gameType = $rows['gameType'];
   $gametitle = $rows['gameSubTitle'];

   echo $gameLength;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix this is your code and that should fix the error.

`$sql="SELECT * FROM games WHERE postId ='".$postId."' ";`

If you want all the records you can use a while loop. Here is some pseudo code.

```
while($row = mysql_fect_assoc($query)){
      echo $row["THE THING YOU WANT"];
      ...
}
```